# How to create multiple pages in a client theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, pages

How do you go about creating multiple pages in a single theme?

Say a clients existing website is just a non wordpress site, using multiple HTML pages and a single CSS stylesheet. You have a homepage at index.html, an about page: about.html and a contact page: contact.html, and so forth.

The tutorials and documentation that I've read so far, just seem to cover making a wordpress theme, that utilizes a single index.html page. SO it seems like you are forced in a sense to  have a single page website layout?

Is there a way for me to create a wordpress theme with multiple pages? So the client installs the theme, and then thats it, the website is setup?

Comment: I suggest reading through the [Theme Basics](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/) chapters for a good overview of things.

Comment: Specifically this [page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/).